# SQL insert statement elegance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to populate temp table as below:

```
declare @FromDate datetime = '20210901'
    , @toDate datetime = '20211231'
    , @2ndDate datetime = '20210930'
    , @3rdDate datetime = '20211031'
    , @4thDate datetime = '20211130'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StkCost') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #StkCost

create table #StkCost
(

iStockid int
, iwarehouseid int
, Latest_date DateTime

)

insert into #StkCost
SELECT iStockID, iWarehouseID, MAX (dTxDate) AS Latest_Date
    FROM _etblInvCostTracking 
    WHERE fQtyOnHand <> '0' and dTxDate < @ToDate 
    GROUP BY iStockID, iWarehouseID 

insert into #StkCost
SELECT iStockID, iWarehouseID, MAX (dTxDate) AS Latest_Date
    FROM _etblInvCostTracking 
    WHERE fQtyOnHand <> '0' and dTxDate < @2ndDate 
    GROUP BY iStockID, iWarehouseID 

insert into #StkCost
SELECT iStockID, iWarehouseID, MAX (dTxDate) AS Latest_Date
    FROM _etblInvCostTracking 
    WHERE fQtyOnHand <> '0' and dTxDate < @3rdDate
    GROUP BY iStockID, iWarehouseID 

insert into #StkCost
SELECT iStockID, iWarehouseID, MAX (dTxDate) AS Latest_Date
    FROM _etblInvCostTracking 
    WHERE fQtyOnHand <> '0' and dTxDate < @4thDate 
    GROUP BY iStockID, iWarehouseID 

insert into #StkCost
SELECT iStockID, iWarehouseID, MAX (dTxDate) AS Latest_Date
    FROM _etblInvCostTracking 
    WHERE fQtyOnHand <> '0' and dTxDate < @toDate 
    GROUP BY iStockID, iWarehouseID 


select * from #StkCost order by Latest_date
```

Select * from #tempTable is just for my own reference.

All the Declare dates will be as a result of a calculation on the report selection.

Is there a way to make it more elegant than all the insert statements?

Comment: Is `@FromDate` needed? You never reference it.

Comment: `@toDate datetime = '20211231` If you're only interested in dates, then use DATE datatype. If the associated column is datetime and has a range of values for the time part, then your logic is incorrect and you need an **exclusive** upper boundary.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this, but perhaps a table variable with your dates would work:

```sql
DECLARE @Dates table (ToDate date);
INSERT INTO @Dates (ToDate)
VALUES('20211231'),
      ('20210930'),
      ('20211031'),
      ('20211130');

SELECT ICT.iStockID,
       ICT.iWarehouseID,
       --D.ToDate, --Not sure if you need this or not
       MAX(ICT.dTxDate) AS Latest_Date
FROM dbo._etblInvCostTracking ICT
     JOIN @Dates D ON ICT.dTxDate < D.ToDate
WHERE ICT.fQtyOnHand <> '0' --Should this not be an int, rather than a varchar?
GROUP BY ICT.iStockID,
         ICT.iWarehouseID,
         D.ToDate;
```